# h5py In-Memory File and Multiprocessing Error

Tags: python, multiprocessing, hdf5, in-memory, h5py

This one's for you HDF5 *and* multiprocessing gurus... First of all, I know that the python h5py and multiprocessing modules don't necessarily like eachother, but I'm getting an error that I just can't figure out.  The script I'm working on creates a temporary *in-memory* hdf5 file, stores data from a (pickle) input file in the in-memory file, and then a multiprocessing Pool performs (read-only) operations on the data from the temp HDF5 file.

I've been able to isolate the code that's causing the error, so here's a simplified code snippet.  When I create an *in-memory* hdf5 file within a generator function, and then use that generator to yield arguments for a multiprocessing Pool, I get a series of HDF5 errors.  Here's some code that's as simple as I could make it to recreate the error:

```
import h5py
from multiprocessing import Pool
from itertools import imap

useMP = True

def doNothing(arg):
    print "Do nothing with %s"%arg

def myGenerator():
    print "Create hdf5 in-memory file..."
    hdfFile = h5py.File('test.hdf',driver='core',backing_store=False)
    print "Finished creating hdf5 in-memory file."
    yield 3.14159
    '''
    # uncommenting this section will result in yet another HDF5 error.
    print "Closing hdf5 in-memory file..."
    hdfFile.close()
    print "Finished closing hdf5 in-memory file."
    '''

if useMP:
    pool = Pool(1)
    mapFunc = pool.imap
else:
    mapFunc = imap

data = [d for d in mapFunc(doNothing,myGenerator())]
```

When I use itertools.imap (set "useMP=False"), I get the following output, as expected:

```
Create hdf5 in-memory file...
Finished creating hdf5 in-memory file.
Do nothing with 0
```

But when I use Pool.imap, even if the pool was created with only a single worker thread, I get this output:

```
Create hdf5 in-memory file...
HDF5-DIAG: Error detected in HDF5 (1.8.9) thread 139951680009984:
  #000: ../../../src/H5F.c line 1538 in H5Fopen(): unable to open file
    major: File accessability
    minor: Unable to open file
  #001: ../../../src/H5F.c line 1227 in H5F_open(): unable to open file: time = Wed Feb 27 09:32:32 2013
, name = 'test.hdf', tent_flags = 1
    major: File accessability
    minor: Unable to open file
  #002: ../../../src/H5FD.c line 1101 in H5FD_open(): open failed
    major: Virtual File Layer
    minor: Unable to initialize object
  #003: ../../../src/H5FDcore.c line 464 in H5FD_core_open(): unable to open file
    major: File accessability
    minor: Unable to open file
Finished creating hdf5 in-memory file.
Do nothing with 0
```

Strange thing is, this error doesn't crash the program.  The script I'm writing that led to this error actually works as I would expect - but it gives the above error for every single in-memory file it creates.  No errors when using itertools.imap, no errors when reading an existing HDF5 file, only the combination of multiprocessing and in-memory HDF5 files.

h5py version 2.1.1

hdf5 version 1.8.9

Python version 2.7.3

Answer (score 2):

After digging around in some h5py files, I've found a parital answer, though still incomplete.  The h5py.File class is defined in [h5py/_hl/files.py](https://github.com/h5py/h5py/blob/master/h5py/_hl/files.py).  The error occurs during the File object creation in the call to make_fid():

```
def make_fid(name, mode, userblock_size, fapl):
    """ Get a new FileID by opening or creating a file.
    Also validates mode argument."""
    ...
    elif mode == 'a' or mode is None:
        try:
            fid = h5f.open(name, h5f.ACC_RDWR, fapl=fapl)
            try:
                existing_fcpl = fid.get_create_plist()
                if userblock_size is not None and existing_fcpl.get_userblock() != userblock_size:
                    raise ValueError("Requested userblock size (%d) does not match that of existing file (%d)" % (userblock_size, existing_fcpl.get_userblock()))
            except:
                fid.close()
                raise
        except IOError:
            fid = h5f.create(name, h5f.ACC_EXCL, fapl=fapl, fcpl=fcpl)
```

If the file exists, it is opened in read/write mode.  If it does not exist (which is the case for in-memory files), the h5f.open() call raises an exception.  It's this call to h5f.open that is triggering the H5Fopen() error message.

The question that is still open is why the error is only printed when using multiprocessing?  First of all, I was assuming that the generator function that creates the HDF5 files was being called by the main thread.  Well, it's not.  The multiprocessing Pool actually creates a new thread to handle tasks for imap and imap_unordered, but not for map/map_async.  Replace pool.imap with pool.map, and the generator function is called from the main thread, and no error messages are printed.  So why would HDF5 file creation in a separate thread raise an error?

**-------- UPDATE -----------**

Apparently, h5py automatically silences HDF5 error messages in the main thread, since h5py handles the errors instead.  However, it does NOT yet automatically silence the errors in child threads.  The solution: `h5py._errors.silence_errors()`.  This function disables automatic HDF5 error printing in the current thread.  See h5py [issue 206](https://code.google.com/p/h5py/issues/detail?id=206).  This code silences the HDF5 errors:

```
import h5py
from multiprocessing import Pool
from itertools import imap
import threading

useMP = True

def doNothing(arg):
    print "Do nothing with %s"%arg

def myGenerator():
    h5py._errors.silence_errors()
    print "Create hdf5 in-memory file..."
    hdfFile = h5py.File('test.hdf',driver='core',backing_store=False)
    print "Finished creating hdf5 in-memory file."
    yield 3.14159

if useMP:
    pool = Pool(1)
    mapFunc = pool.map
else:
    mapFunc = imap

data = [d for d in mapFunc(doNothing,myGenerator())]
```

Comment: The same thing is apparently true for threading and multiprocessing:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33182182/atypical-error-silencing-for-h5py-and-threads